# Apply a URL rewrite rule on Typo3 website using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, url-rewrite-module

I have a url rewrite rule that works fine on my local server (xampp) , but when I put it inside the .htaccess of a typo3 site won't work . This is how this rule looks like :

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /test/$1.html [L,R]
```

and she redirects every request that ends up with www.site.com/name/ to www.site.com/name.html with showing the .html extension in the url bar . Like I said , this rewrite rule works successfully on my local server , but applied on a normal website ( not a typo3 ) , the .htaccess of the typo3 website contains a hole bunch of other rewrite rules written by another programmer , so these are the 2 rational reasons that preventing it from working :

1st : the already in .htaccess existing rewrite rules overwrite the one I created (eventhough when I add it at the very bottom of the file )

2nd : maybe because the structure of the typo3 cms is different , which I don't really think it can affect on the .htaccess rules , but .. I still find it a possible reason (unless someone confirm me the opposite).

I would really appreciate it if someone could really help me making it work using the .htaccess file and not relying on one of the extension like RealUrl .

Comment: no , actually the test folder exists only on my localserver , in typo3 I have this structure   \www\typo3\folder\.htaccess

Comment: Ok can you show full content of `\www\typo3\folder\.htaccess`?

Comment: so for the phpinfo statement I can't make it work , I uploaded the info.php file to the server , but because of rewrite rules , I can't access that file and I'm not allowed to stop them (even for a while) , the .htaccess file contains 4250 lines of rewrite rule definitions and other stuff , so would you like that I send it to you even though ? if yes , give me your email address or email me at anass.rakibi[a]gmail.com

Comment: 4520 line .htaccess is scary. You can upload it on pastebin.com and leave link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MmCb7uNn

Comment: and ? have you taken a look ?

Comment: Yes I have but these are just too many rules. For testing purpose you will need to reduce it down to few core rules only and that can reproduce the problem

Comment: so do you think the problem why it's not working is because the too many rewriting rules that already exist in the file ??!!!

Comment: Difficult to say because there are just too many rules out there.

Comment: OK well thank you anyway for your help :) I really appreciate it